# php CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT error

Tags: php, arrays, curl

i was trying some thing but it doenst seem to work out that well.. it only outputs CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT & No URL set! how can i fix this?..

*It needs to echo out the text on the page $link1*

```
    <?php
        $link1 = "http://www.lubbo-zone.nl/script2/?name=iChris.";

        $ch = curl_init();

        $opts = [ 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' => 1 ,   'CURLOPT_URL' => "{$link1}"];

        curl_setopt_array($ch , array($opts));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
        echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';

        var_dump($response);
    ?>
```

Comment: What are you wanting to happen?  "doesn't work" isn't a good description.

Comment: It needs to echo out the $link1 so i can use the code from that link for a image generator. @Teepeemm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your code. You are wrapping the options array in another array

```
$opts = [ 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' => 1 ,   'CURLOPT_URL' => "{$link1}"];

curl_setopt_array($ch , array($opts)); // ends up being array(array(...opts))
```

Change the line `curl_setopt_array($ch , array($opts));` to `curl_setopt_array($ch , $opts);`

Here is the entire code. Your `CURLOPT_` constants should NOT be quoted either

```
<?php
$link1 = "http://www.lubbo-zone.nl/script2/?name=iChris.";

$ch = curl_init();

// your CURLOPT_ constants should NOT be quoted either
$opts = [ CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1 , CURLOPT_URL => $link1];

curl_setopt_array($ch , $opts);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';

var_dump($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this, it gets back me response from the server, page that says checking your browser, but after some seconds redirect to some other URL.

So, I'm pretty sure you're setting options in wrong way.

```
$link1 = "http://www.lubbo-zone.nl/script2/?name=iChris.";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
    echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';

    var_dump ($response);
```

This is what I get

[image]

Comment: with this code that is in my answer? you still get URL not set?

Comment: with your code i get the same as you have but i dont know how to use curl on cloudflare and i searched many posts on stack for it but not a single answer that works

Comment: sites hosted with cloudflare having an extra layer of protection, so either you've to use selenium or use `phantom JS` to get  pass to that page, and  do have a close look how next URL is being formatted, as this is url `http://www.lubbo-zone.nl/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?jschl_vc=a3a1417a04ca6c59eae84a24e7912bf5&pass=1446415783.991-JWorDSaw2H&jschl_answer=-5` so when first response comes back from server, it has special header that is being used in this url that is `Refresh:8;URL=/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?pass=1446415783.991-JWorDSaw2H` find the other ones and format url and hit that url

Comment: huh? selenium? @Mubin

Comment: yes, if you know how to use that. Good Luck mate :)

Comment: even php is difficult so.. @mubin